# Подключение библиотеки в C++

Tags: c++, linux, debian, visual-studio-code, gcc

Я пользователь линукс debiab. Скачал vs code и установил компилятор g++. Написал код для теста. Собственно, код делает окно и окрашивает его в какой-то цвет. Для работы нужна библиотека. Я её подключил следующим образом: #include <GL/freeglut.h>. Но при компиляции (g++ hello.cpp -o hello) у меня компилятор жалуется, что нет такого файла или каталога (GL/freeglut.h). Мне нужна помощь с тем, где взять эту библиотеку, как правильно подключить. Я просто новичок, в виндовс есть vs, которая делает всё за тебя - просто укажи пути к файлам, и компилятор всё сделает.
P.S. я надеюсь, что библиотеку нужно просто правильно поместить в папку с фалом.cpp. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]